# Is there an example of how to build dynamic routes in an Angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

If you follow the angular tutorial, routing seems to be done in the following manner:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroesComponent
  }
])
```

There are some additional things that you can do at this point depending on the size of the application, such as moving the array of the routes to a seperate file/class.

But what I want to achieve is the ability to load these routes on Angular application startup. So the desired flow is something like:

- Load your index.html
- One of the steps would be to load a menu from a rest service. Assume here that the menu knows about the components of the Angular application.
- The response of this rest service call will then be used to create all the desired routes for the application.

So the desired behavior here to is change the angular url routes so that this application can adapt either for localization (english -> french) or a domain change (retail -> financial) because the nature of this app is such that it can be applied to different domains given the correct configuration.

Is this at all possible? If it is, then I am completely stuck on how to approach this problem.

Based on my current understanding, one of the ways to achieve this is to make this service call before or during the bootstrap phase of the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can reset the routes.

Take a look at the official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#resetConfig-anchor

```js
constructor(private _router: Router) {}

yourFunctionToResetTheRouter() {
   this._router.resetConfig([
      { path: 'team/:id', component: TeamCmp,
         children: [
            { path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp },
            { path: 'user/:name', component: UserCmp }
         ] }
   ]);
}
```